# Laravel route not defined error

Tags: php, laravel, url, laravel-5, routes

I keep getting route not defined error and if I use `url()` I get server can not provide a secure connection error.
I hope I can get some help.

route

```
Route::get('/show/{table_name}/{product_id}', 'PageCotroller@showdetails')->name('product-show');
```

View:

```
<h4><a href="{{ url('product-show' .$table_name . '/' .$product->item_id)}}">{{ $product->title }}</a></h4>
```

Controller:

```
   public function showdetails($table_name,$pid){

       $categories = Category::all();
       $data['product_id']=$pid;
       $data['table']=$table_name;
       $shop_name=Shop::all();
       $query = DB::table($table_name)
       ->select('*')
       ->where('item_id', '=', $pid)
       ->get();;
       $image=Item_image::all();
           $pro_img = DB::table('item_images')
               ->select('image_loc')
               ->where('prod_id', $pid)
               ->get();
   return view('show_details',compact('categories','image','pro_img','table_name','shop_name'));

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To call a route by name, you should use the [`route`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/helpers#method-route) function and add the parameters in an array as the second parameter.

```
route('product-show', [$table_name, $product->item_id])
```

The reason you get a route not defined error is that you are generating the url `/product-show/{table_name}/{product_id}` and the actual url is `/show/{table_name}/{product_id}`. Also, adding the parameters manually is bad practice when there are many helper functions that do this for you.

Answer (score 0):

change view address

```
<h4><a href="{{ url('product-show/' .$table_name . '/' .$product->item_id)}}">{{ $product->title }}</a></h4>
```

OR

> use *[route](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/helpers#method-route)* helper laravel