# Laravel error: route not defined

Tags: php, laravel-5

Possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44656442/laravel-route-not-defined-error). But unable to get the answer in my case.

I need to use a link on my Laravel website, but it keeps resulting in "route not defined" error.

Html:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
@auth
    <li>
        <a href="{{ route('add-post') }}">Add post</a>
    </li>
@endauth
</ul>
```

web.php:

```
Route::get('/add-post', 'PagesController@add_post');
```

PagesController:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class PagesController extends Controller
{
    public function add_post()
    {
        return view('add-post');
    }
}
```

Comment: Any chance of feedback on the answer at all?

Answer (score 2):

So you basically have two options here. When you use the `route` function, Laravel is looking for a named route. In order to name a route, you can add `->name('name-of-route-here')` at the end of your route definition.

If you don't want to name your route, you can just use the `url` helper function instead of `route`, so your code would be `url('add-post')`

Documentation on named routes: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing#named-routes
Documentation on `url` function: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/helpers#method-url

Answer (score 1):

You need to name the route in order to do that:

For example:

`Route::get('/add-post', 'PagesController@add_post')->name('add-post);`

This is because when you use `route('add-post')` are are requesting a URL based on the name set in the web.php file

Comment: This was the first anwser i've tried and which worked. Thanks!

Comment: @YvesSterckx no problem! Can you accept it as helpful please? (The tick icon next to the question)

Answer (score 0):

Just change this:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
   @auth
     <li>
      <a href="{{ url('add-post') }}">Add post</a>
   </li>
   @endauth
```

web.php:

```
Route::get('add-post', 'PagesController@add_post');
```