# Route Not Defined - Blade Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

My problem is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44656442/laravel-route-not-defined-error) but solution is not working.

> Route [postThisAppraisal] not defined. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\laraveladmin\resources\views\admin\appraisals\fillAppraisal.blade.php)

My route in web.php is as following: (without any namespace)

```
Route::post('/postThisAppraisal', 'PublicController@postThisAppraisal')->name('postThisAppraisal');
```

And in blade.php i am calling it like following:

```
<form action="{{ route("postThisAppraisal") }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

I have even defined it in `PublicController` as following:

```
public function postThisAppraisal(){
    return "submitted";
}
```

Comment: Use `php artisan route:list` to show your routes and make sure it is there. Try `php artisan route:clear` to clear route cache.

Comment: php artisan route:clear this command worked. Thank you please post this as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `php artisan route:list` to show a list of registered routes - make sure it shows up there. If it doesn't, use `php artisan route:clear` to clear Laravel's route cache