# Search function get [route not defined error] in Laravel8

Tags: laravel

I'm studying search funciton.
I use Laravel Framework 8.48.2

I made search function before at Laravel5 and it works very fine.
This time I use same code into my current Laravel8 project
but I got this error

> Route [products.order] not defined

Could you teach me right code please?

> WEB.php

```
Route::get('products/search', [ProductController::class, 'search']);
Route::post('products/search', [ProductController::class, 'order'])->name('products.search');
```

> Controller

```
//search page
   public function search()
    {
        $products = Product::get();
        return view('products.search',compact('products'))
            ->with('i', (request()->input('page', 1) - 1) * 5);
    }

//result page
    public function order(Request $request)
    {
        $data = $request->all();
        $images = Product::when($data['color'], function ($query, $color) {
            return $query->where('color', $color);
        })->
        when($data['w_m'], function ($query, $w_m) {
            return $query->where('w_m', $w_m);
        })->get();

        return view('products.result', compact('products'));
    }
```

> search.blade.php( only form action part)

```
<form action="{{ route('search') }}" class="form-image-upload" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: Where did u get this error - Route [products.order] not defined? (file, line)

Comment: You have not defined the route... The one that exists is `products.search` but not `products.order`...

Comment: Dear @Ryan Nghiem Thank you for helping me  I got this error http://127.0.0.1:8000/products/search

Comment: Dear @matiaslauriti  Thank you. Yes I can see it say not defined but I don't know how. Could you teach me where to fix it please?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel route not defined error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44656442/laravel-route-not-defined-error)

Comment: @matiaslauriti That's not my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your post action, you are actually asking to do action with a route name "search" which is not assigned in route therefore it's undefined. Can you try to change as following?

```
Route::get('products/search', [ProductController::class, 'search'])->name('search');
```